# Avoid 'index not in range' on nested loops encrypting chunks of string

Tags: python, nested-loops

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(o):
        orderedList.append(newStringList[j][i])
```

*I'm a beginner Python programmer*
I have an encryption problem to solve, in which I must split a string into chunks of n size, then add the first index of each to a list, then the second index of each, etc. I have a solution to the problem that works when all chunks are equal, however, the last chunk can sometimes be smaller if len(string)%n != 0. When this occurs the above loop I have for adding chars to the list goes out of range and the program doesn't work. Is there any solution for this.

**Edit**
Seems I was a bit unclear
The encryption takes a string e.g. "123456789" and a number n e.g. 3. Then divides the string into chunks of size n. So newStringList[123,456,789]. I then take the first element from newStringList[0] to newStringList[n-1], then moves onto the second element and so on. So orderedList[1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9]. Now you have a better backdrop for the above problem.

Comment: I'm not following you.

Comment: To allow people to help you more accurately, you should always precise what is stored in your variables before  (here `newStringList` and `orderedList`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding one if condition before the last line will fix the issue. The if condition is to make sure that you are accessing the array list only when the element exist.

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(o):
        if j < len(newStringList) and i < len(newStringList[j]) :
              orderedList.append(newStringList[j][i])
```

Comment: This just gives me a blank list, I've added more info above if that helps

Comment: The comparison operators are wrong. With `j<len(newStringList)` and `i<len(newStringList[j])` this should work and is probably what the task was really about.

Comment: @Jasper Aha! Works perfectly, and is a better solution than the exception above. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way of chunking strings, which doesn't mind if the last chunk is too short:

```
def ChunkString( string, n=8 ):
   return [ string[ i:i+n ] for i in range( 0, len( string ), n ) ]
```

For example:

```
>>> ChunkString('123456789')
['12345678', '9']
```

Another approach that might be appropriate in an encryption context is to pad each string before you go in so that its length is divisible by `n`:

```
def PadString( string, n=8, padChar='*' ):
    return string + padChar * ( -len( string ) % n )
```

Here are some example outputs:

```
>>> PadString('1')
'1*******'
>>> PadString('1234567')
'1234567*'
>>> PadString('12345678')
'12345678'
```

A solution for your updated problem would look like this:

```
chunks = ChunkString( '12345678', 3 )

from itertools import izip_longest, chain
reordered = chain( *izip_longest( *chunks ) )
print( [ x for x in reordered if x is not None ] )
```

Comment: I already had a function which split it into the chunks I wanted. It's just when I use a loop to add elements from the last, smaller chunk the index goes out of range

Comment: @PFOD1998  You can use `itertools.izip_longest` and `itertools.chain`—see edit.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options:

1) Ask for forgiveness, a.k.a. use [Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html):

```
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(o):
      try:
        orderedList.append(newStringList[j][i])
      except IndexError:
        break
```

2) Pad the string to a suitable length:

```
if not len(inputStr) % n:
  inputStr += '*' * (n - len(inputStr) % n)
```

3) Use fancy methods:
for Python 2.7:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]]
orderedList = [filter(None,x) for x in itertools.izip_longest(*a)]

-> [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6)]
```

and for Python 3.x:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]]
orderedList = [list(filter(None,x)) for x in itertools.zip_longest(*a)]

-> [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6)]
```

This method uses the [(i)zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) function (spelt with i for Python 2.7) that zips multiple lists and pads them automatically.

Comment: The exception worked perfectly thank you. I hadn't learnt about them at my class yet so I'm glad of your help